# Do protesters pay to enter the zoo?

Tags: planet-zoo

When a group of animal rights protesters enters the zoo, do they pay the zoo admission fee like other guests?

Comment: I vaguely recall checking for this at some point and I don't think they do (there's the greedy dude in the campaign saying something like "I don't mind the protesters as long as they pay the entrance fee"). Don't take my word for it though.

Comment: Great question title, out of context.

Answer (score -1):

Yes everyone that enters a zoo has to pay except first responders if an incident has happened, other then that everyone has to pay

Comment: Hi ShadedCloux, do you have any way to back this up? Is it based on your experience, is it something you read? Answers will be better received if they show some effort and background information. Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. And, finally, welcome to Arqade!